# RouterLink not working when called inside an HTML code assigned to a typescript variable

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm working with Angular 9, and trying to assign html code to a variable and then add it to the main html code using innerHtml. Here is my code:

app.component.ts:

```
myVariable=`<div class="row">
              <button class="button button-1 text-center mx-auto" 
               routerLink="/myForm">
              <i class="fas fa-hotel"></i>Go to the next page</button>
            </div>`
   
  ngOnInit(): void {
         document.getElementById('mainText').innerHTML = this.myVariable ;
  }
```

Everything is working fine except for the routerLink which is not redirecting to the Url "/myForm" as expected.

app.component.html:

```
<mat-dialog-content>
  <section>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="mainText">
    </div>
  </section>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

NB: The routing works correctly when added directly in app.component.html so it's not a RouterModule importing problem.

Comment: Can you include the HTML that this code generates? That could help others to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Are you getting any sort of error in console?

Comment: @iamentafaz there is no error in the console